# unable to locate href element within a mouse over area - Selenium web driver

Tags: java, eclipse, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I tried to locate a link "Sign in" located in the window which appeared when mouse move on to "Mail" link on [Yahoo](https://www.yahoo.com/). I can get the xpath using firebug. but when i used it in the script, it doesn't work.

[image]

HTML snippet :

```
<a id="yui_3_18_0_4_1456816269995_943" class="C($menuLink) Fw(b) Td(n)" 
    data-ylk="t3:usr;elm:btn;elmt:lgn;" data-action-outcome="lgn" 
    href="login.yahoo.com/config/…; data-rapid_p="23">Sign in</a>
```

I tried this in my code within main method,

```
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("uh-mail-link"));
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
    driver.findElement(By.id("yui_3_18_0_4_1456804882382_929")).click();
```

id selecter;

```
driver.findElement(By.id("yui_3_18_0_4_1456804882382_929")).click();
```

It prompts this error;

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"yui_3_18_0_4_1456804882382_929"}
Command duration or timeout: 17 milliseconds
```

Can we locate it using id of appeared window  ".//*[@id='yui_3_18_0_4_1456804882382_919']"  and linkText "Sign in", or are there any other methods to locate it in the script.

Comment: html snippets of target element are here    :   <a class="C($menuLink) Fw(b) Td(n)" data-ylk="t3:usr;elm:btn;elmt:lgn;" data-action-outcome="lgn" href="https://login.yahoo.com/config/login?.src=fpctx&.intl=us&.lang=en-US&.done=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.yahoo.com">Sign in</a>

Answer (score 1):

You're supposed to pass just *id* to `By.id()`, not an XPath expression :

```
driver.findElement(By.id("yui_3_18_0_4_1456804882382_929")).click();
```

or use `By.xpath()` instead of `By.id()` if you need to find the element by XPath expression, for example, by using combination of `id` and link text to locate the target element.

**UPDATE :**

You can filter element by its text content and id like so :

```
//a[@id='yui_3_18_0_4_1456816269995_943' and .='Sign in']
```

Comment: sorry for that mistake. I tried using id and xpath, but errors are same. how i combine both id and linkText using xpath expression.

Comment: Could you post HTML snippet of the target element?

Comment: html snippets of target element are here    :   <a class="C($menuLink) Fw(b) Td(n)" data-ylk="t3:usr;elm:btn;elmt:lgn;" data-action-outcome="lgn" href="https://login.yahoo.com/config/login?.src=fpctx&.intl=us&.lang=en-US&.done=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.yahoo.com">Sign in</a>

Comment: <a id="yui_3_18_0_4_1456816269995_943" class="C($menuLink) Fw(b) Td(n)" data-ylk="t3:usr;elm:btn;elmt:lgn;" data-action-outcome="lgn" href="https://login.yahoo.com/config/login?.src=fpctx&.intl=us&.lang=en-US&.done=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.yahoo.com" data-rapid_p="23">Sign in</a>

Comment: I think id is dynamic. so is that possible to use id.

Comment: see **UPDATE** section. Just remove the id filter if you think it is dynamic.

Comment: previously i tried it using  text "Sign in" without id, it locates the element "Sign in" link next to Notification icon "bell" not the "sign in" in prompted window.

Comment: @TharinduKandegedara Please post the relevant HTML part i.e portion that includes "Sign in" texts. I can't suggest anything if it involves HTML that isn't shown in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting 2 functions ? 1 for mouse over and 1 for actual clicking ? 
I have a sample in Java if you need.

```
public void mouseOver(String xPath){ 
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xPath));
        action.moveToElement(element).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath(xPath))).click().build().perform();
        Thread.sleep(500); //too actualy see if is it performs
}
public void click(String xpath) {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).click();
}
```

You can change the searching method from xpath to id, or whatever you need.
Be aware that the mouseOver function has a different xpath/id to send from the click method because , you mouseOver on first button, and you click the other link that will apear after.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I edited the question. i mentioned how i used mouseover event. but the problem is to find correct xpath.

Comment: Have you tried driver.findElement(By.className("C($menuLink) Fw(b) Td(n)")).click();  ? Or put a Thread.sleep(1000) after mouse over and before the actual clicking